# Search Column using Case in all workbook and copy all row value in current active Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am using "folder select dialogue" to select folder. Now I want to search specific column in
all workbooks. If matched then dependent all row values should be fetch in current active workbook.

For example date, it will check date column using case statement in all workbooks if matched then it is showing only one row’s value. I think there is something problem in loop or `Rows.End(xlDown).Value`.

Your help or assistance will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExtractFigures2()
    Dim WSDest As Worksheet
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim WS_Src As Worksheet
    Dim Shp As Shape
    Dim a As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim FilterStr As String
    Dim FN As String
    Dim fso, oFolder, oSubfolder, oFile, queue As Collection
    Dim xSheet As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set WSDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With WSDest
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
 Dim fileName, ws As Worksheet
 Dim rng As Range
 Dim destWB As Workbook
 Dim pPath As String
 Dim ShellApp As Object
 Dim fileNameC As String
 Dim Prompt As String
 Dim OpenAt As String
 Dim col As Variant
 Dim I As Integer
 Dim rngData As Range




 Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, Prompt, 0, OpenAt)

 On Error Resume Next
 MyPath = ShellApp.self.Path
 MsgBox MyPath
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''


    FilterStr = "*.xls*"

    'FilterStr = "*.xls*" ' That was in used
     'FilterStr = "*.xls?" 'All files

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set queue = New Collection
    queue.Add fso.GetFolder(MyPath)

    Do While queue.Count > 0
        Set oFolder = queue(1)
        queue.Remove 1 'dequeue
         '...insert any folder processing code here...
        For Each oSubfolder In oFolder.SubFolders
            queue.Add oSubfolder 'enqueue
        Next oSubfolder
        For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
            FN = fso.GetFileName(oFile)
            If FN Like FilterStr Then
                Set WB = Workbooks.Open(oFile, False)

      '********************************

      '********************************
       Set WS_Src = WB.Worksheets("Sheet1")



                'If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                '''MsgBox "Worksheet does not exist"
                'Set WS_Src = WB.Worksheets("Layout ")
                'Else
                'MsgBox "Worksheet exists"
                'End If

                'Or WS_Src = WB.Worksheets("Layout ") Or WS_Src = WB.Worksheets("Lay out")




                With WS_Src
                     'Write filename to sheet
                    WSDest.Range("A" & lastRow) = _
                    Left(FN, InStr(FN, ".") - 1)

                     'Range A1:CE1 Have a Column/Parameter Value
                     'Set col = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:CE1").Value

                    For Each col In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:CE1")
                    'For Each col In Cells.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

                    Select Case col

                          Case "Date"
                            WSDest.Range("B" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Cells.CurrentRegion.Rows.End(xlDown).Value
                            'col.End(xlDown)
                            'col.Cells.CurrentRegion.Rows.End(xlDown).Value is giving me value of one row,I want all row value
                            'col.Value
                            'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
                            MsgBox Cells.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

                          Case "Vendor"
                            WSDest.Range("C" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Region ID"
                            WSDest.Range("D" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Circle"
                            WSDest.Range("E" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "BSC ID"
                            WSDest.Range("F" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Cell ID"
                            WSDest.Range("G" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Sector ID"
                            WSDest.Range("H" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "City/Town"
                            WSDest.Range("I" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Lattude/Longitude"
                            WSDest.Range("J" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "1X BTSID"
                            WSDest.Range("K" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "BTS Friendly Name"
                            WSDest.Range("L" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Total Usage"
                            WSDest.Range("M" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Primary Usage"
                            WSDest.Range("N" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "SHO Factor"
                            WSDest.Range("O" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Access Terminal (AT) Attempts"
                            WSDest.Range("P" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Access Terminal (AT) Failures"
                            WSDest.Range("Q" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Access Terminal (AT) Fail% (>2%)"
                            WSDest.Range("R" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Access Terminal (AT) Blocks"
                            WSDest.Range("S" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Access Terminal (AT) Block% (>2%)"
                            WSDest.Range("T" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Access Network (AN) Attempts"
                            WSDest.Range("U" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Access Network (AN) Failures"
                            WSDest.Range("V" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Access Network (AN) Fail% (>2%)"
                            WSDest.Range("W" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value


                          Case "Access Network (AN) Blocks"
                            WSDest.Range("X" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value


                          Case "Access Network (AN) Block% (>2%)"
                            WSDest.Range("Y" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Total Attempts"
                            WSDest.Range("Z" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Total Failures"
                            WSDest.Range("AA" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Total Fail% (>2%)"
                            WSDest.Range("AB" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Total Blocks"
                            WSDest.Range("AC" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Total Block% (>2%)"
                            WSDest.Range("AD" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Session Failed Calls"
                            WSDest.Range("AE" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Session Failed Calls% (>2%)"
                            WSDest.Range("AF" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Session Blocks"
                            WSDest.Range("AG" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value


                          Case "Session Block% (>2%)"
                            WSDest.Range("AH" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Drop Calls"
                            WSDest.Range("AI" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "DCR% (>5%)"
                            WSDest.Range("AJ" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Connection Setup Time (msec)"
                            WSDest.Range("AK" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Unicast Access Terminal Identifier (UATI) Requests"
                            WSDest.Range("AL" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Unicast Access Terminal Identifier (UATI) Failures"
                            WSDest.Range("AM" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Unicast Access Terminal Identifier (UATI) Failures (%) (>2%)"
                            WSDest.Range("AN" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Session Configuration Success Rate (<95%)"
                            WSDest.Range("AO" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Authentications Attempts"
                            WSDest.Range("AP" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Authentications Failures"
                            WSDest.Range("AQ" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Authentications Failures (%) (>2%)"
                            WSDest.Range("AR" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "A13 Idle Transfer Attempts"
                            WSDest.Range("AS" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "A13 Idle Transfer Failure (%) (>2%)"
                            WSDest.Range("AT" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Fwd Slot Occp (%)"
                            WSDest.Range("AU" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "FTCH Slot Occp (%)"
                            WSDest.Range("AV" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "CCH Slot Occp%"
                            WSDest.Range("AW" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "ACH Occp%"
                            WSDest.Range("AX" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Avg DRC Request (kbps)"
                            WSDest.Range("AY" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Fwd Sector Thrput including Buffering Delay (kbps)"
                            WSDest.Range("AZ" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Fwd Data Served Volume (MB)"
                            WSDest.Range("BA" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Fwd Data Served Time (sec)"
                            WSDest.Range("BB" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Fwd Sector Thrput when Served (kbps)"
                            WSDest.Range("BC" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Effective Fwd Sector Thrput (kbps) (>1.2 Mbps)"
                            WSDest.Range("BD" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "% Utilization"
                            WSDest.Range("BE" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Rev Data Received Volume (MB)"
                            WSDest.Range("BF" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Rev Data Served Time (sec)"
                            WSDest.Range("BG" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Rev Sector Thrput when received (kbps)"
                            WSDest.Range("BH" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Effective Rev Sector Thrput (kbps"
                            WSDest.Range("BI" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Radio Link Protocal (RLP) Fwd Data Volume (MB)"
                            WSDest.Range("BJ" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "RLP Fwd ReTrx Bytes (MB)"
                            WSDest.Range("BK" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "RLP Fwd ReTrx Rate%"
                            WSDest.Range("BL" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Ratio of Fwd RLP to PL"
                            WSDest.Range("BM" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "RLP Rev Data Volume (MB)"
                            WSDest.Range("BN" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "RLP Rev ReTrx Req Bytes (MB)"
                            WSDest.Range("BO" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "RLP Rev ReTrx Req Rate%"
                            WSDest.Range("BP" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Ratio of Rev RLP to PL"
                            WSDest.Range("BQ" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "HO Attempts"
                            WSDest.Range("BR" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "HO Failures"
                            WSDest.Range("BS" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "HO Failures (%) (>2%)"
                            WSDest.Range("BT" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Abis Blocks"
                            WSDest.Range("BU" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Max Users (>20)"
                            WSDest.Range("BV" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "LongTrm Avg RSSI Rise(dB)"
                            WSDest.Range("BW" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "LongTrm Peak RSSI Rise (dB)"
                            WSDest.Range("BX" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Total Users"
                            WSDest.Range("BY" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                          Case "Date Of Integration"
                            WSDest.Range("BZ" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                            Case "No. of Carriers"
                            WSDest.Range("CA" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                            Case "Cell Call Traffic (Erl)"
                            WSDest.Range("CB" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                            Case "Cell Softer Handoff Traffic (Erl)"
                            WSDest.Range("CC" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                            Case "Cell Soft Handoff Traffic (Erl)"
                            WSDest.Range("CD" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value

                            Case "% Data Loading"
                            WSDest.Range("CE" & lastRow) = _
                            col.Value




                        End Select
                    Next
                    WB.Close False
                    lastRow = lastRow + 1
                End With
            End If
        Next oFile
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line - col.Cells.CurrentRegion.Rows.End(xlDown).Value

Comment: Hello Paresh,
Thank you for your comment, I know that there is a problem in “col.Cells.CurrentRegion.Rows.End(xlDown).Value”

I am unable to find out the way to select all rows for particular column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign the value of variable col in LastRow for specific column, check the below code:

```
WSDest.Range("B" & lastRow) = col.End(xlDown).Value
```

Lets say, **col** represent cell **A1** in range `Range("A1:CE1")` then `col.End(xlDown).Value` will give you the value of last row of column **A** and that value will be assigned to `WSDest.Range("B" & lastRow)`

Comment: Hello Paresh,
Thank you for your assistance. I am still in problem to fetch all row because “WSDest.Range("B" & lastRow) = col.End(xlDown).Value” will fetch only last row.

I think there is a requirement of loop after current Region (Column). 
Cells.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count is reading total row. But I am unable to fix it with loop.

Case "Date"
WSDest.Range("B" & lastRow) = _
col.End(xlDown).Value
MsgBox Cells.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count